# Does this iterating process always returns to 0 for positive $a_0$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Given $a_0$ be an positive integer, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
8a_n,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lfloor a_n/3\rfloor, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Now form the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by performing this operation repeatedly.

Example: $a_0=11,(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(11,88,29,232,77,616,205,1640,546,182,60,20,6,2,0,0,...)$

> *1 Question*: For every $a_0,(a_n)_{n\mathbb{N}}$ will eventually reach the number $0$?

The above claim is true for all $a_0$ up to $10^6$.

*Keith Matthews enlarge conjecture to trajectories starting with a negative integer. Go through Keith Matthews programming to insure mapping,* [link](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/hajari.html)

*Extended Claim*

Let $a_0$ be an positive integer and $k$ be any odd positive integer greater than $1$, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
(k^2-1)a_n,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lfloor a_n/k\rfloor, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Now form the sequence $(a_{n,k})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by performing this operation repeatedly

Example $a_0=11,k=5,(a_{n,5})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(11,264,52,10,2,0,0,...)$

> *2 Question*: For every $a_0$ and odd $k\ge 3$ the sequence $(a_{n,k})_{n\mathbb{N}}$ will eventually reach the number $0$?

*Programming for extended claim by Keith Matthews, including negative values,* [link](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/hajari3.html)

**Extended Collatz conjecture**

Let $a_0$ be an positive integer and $k$ be any even positive integer, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
(k+1)a_n+1,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lceil a_n/k\rceil, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Now form the sequence $(a_{n,k})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by performing this operation repeatedly

*Example* $a_0=5,k=4,(a_{n,k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(5,26,7,36,9,46,12,3,16,4,1,...)$

again we can ask about, every sequence will eventually reach at the number $1$?

*Programming for extended Collatz conjecture by Keith Matthews, including negative values*, [link](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/hajari2.html)

More on extended Collatz conjecture

*First*: Let $a_0,t$ be an positive integer and $k$ be any even positive integer, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
(k^t+k^{t-1})a_n+k^{t-1},  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lceil a_n/k\rceil, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Now form the sequence $(a_{n,k,t})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by performing this operation repeatedly then sequence will eventually reach at the number $1$

*Second*: Let $a_0$ be an positive integer and $k$ be any even positive integer greater than $2$ and $t\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
(k^t+k^{t-2})a_n+k^{t-2},  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lceil a_n/k\rceil, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Now form the sequence $(a_{n,k,t})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by performing this operation repeatedly then sequence will eventually reach at the number $1$

---

I again extend claim on **odd $k$**

*First*: Let $a_0$ be an positive integer and $k$ be any odd positive integer greater than $1$ and $t\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
(k^t-k^{t-2})a_n,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lfloor a_n/k\rfloor, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Then the sequence $(a_{n,k,t})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ will eventually reach at the number $0$

*Second*: Let $a_0$ be an positive integer and $k$ be any odd positive integer greater than $1$ and $t\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, define

$$  a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
(k^t-k^{t-1})a_n,  & \text{if $a_n$ is odd} \\
\lfloor a_n/k\rfloor, & \text{if $a_n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Then the sequence $(a_{n,k,t})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ will eventually reach at the number $0$

Comment: This does not seem any easier than the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: Without getting into exact definitions, the problem "Given a 'Collatz-like' function $g$, does $g^k(n)$ eventually equal $1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?" is undecidable, due to Kurtz & Simon. Your question is in some sense akin to asking whether a specific group presentation has decidable word problem, or whether a fixed Turing machine $T$ halts. That could be interesting (certainly it is interesting e.g. when that Turing machine encodes the Collatz problem itself) but as it currently stands, it's just a question in an infinite family of questions, with nothing to distinguish it from the rest.

Comment: @Carl-Fredrik, I thought that result was due to Conway ("Unpredictable iterations").

Comment: @GerryMyerson Conway showed it is undecidable uniformly in $g$ and $n$. That is, Conway's input is a fixed Collatz-like function $g$ and a natural number $n$. Kurtz & Simon just take a function $g$ as input.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda To clarify, I believe you mean this question is akin to whether a fixed Turing machine halts *on every input*, is that right?

Comment: "undecidable" implies that 1 is not reached sometimes. So if the problem in OP was undecidable, the answer would be "no". Conway has nothing to do with that problem.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, that's right. And to be clear, I am not saying that the problem in the question is undecidable (I don't know whether this particular Turing machine halts on every input).